# Partial string matching in python using re

Tags: python, python-re

Match all lowercase letters which are followed by two or more capital letters then three or more digits: (the capital letters and digits should not be included in the match) in python

I tried this but not working:[a-z]?![A-Z]{2,}[0-9]{3,}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your current approach, but put the capital letters followed by numbers assertion into a positive lookahead:

```regex
[a-z](?=[A-Z]{2,}[0-9]{3,})
```

This pattern says to:

```regex
[a-z]          match a lowercase letter
(?=            then lookahead (but do NOT consume)
    [A-Z]{2,}  2 or more uppercase letters
    [0-9]{3,}  followed by 3 or more digits
)
```

Lookaheads *assert*, but not *consume*, in a regex pattern.